# Global dimension of a quiver with relations that do not overlap

Tags: representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I am reading Green, Hille & Schroll's paper [*Algebras and Varieties*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.07877.pdf) and find myself a bit confused with Proposition 5.1, which says:

Consider a field $K$, a quiver $Q$ and a tip-reduced nonempty set of paths $\mathcal{T}$ such that $kQ/\langle\mathcal{T}\rangle$ is finite dimensional. Then $\text{gldim}(KQ/\langle\mathcal{T}\rangle)=2$ if and only if there are no overlaps among elements of $\mathcal{T}$.

However, if $Q$ is the quiver with a vertex and $1$ loop $x$ and $\mathcal{T}=\{x^2\}$, then the above seems to fail. What is it that I don't understand?

Comment: Might it be that the path $x^2$ is regarded as overlapping itself (with overlap $x$), since $x^2 = px = xq$ for $p = x$ and $q = x$?

Comment: Thanks! I was totally ignoring paths overlapping themselves (which can only happen when we have cycles of length 1?). I think in the notation of the paper, the overlap relation is $o(x^2,x^2,x,x)$, meaning that $x^2\cdot x=x\cdot x^2$, but the details don't matter... Thanks again!